# Ionic3 background image showing only in app.scss

Tags: css, sass, background, ionic3, background-image

I have a structure like this:
--src
--app
----app.scss
--assets
----imgs
------pergamena.jpg
--pages
----start
------start.scss
The image pergamena.jpg is showing only if I put this code in app.scss:

```
.contenutoStart {  
     background: url("../assets/imgs/pergamena.jpg") no-repeat center center 
     fixed;
     background-size: cover;  
     }
```

If I put this code in start.scss the image is not showing:

```
.contenutoStart {  
     background: url("../../assets/imgs/pergamena.jpg") no-repeat center 
center 
     fixed;
     background-size: cover;  
     }
```

The file html is like this:

```
<ion-content class="contenutoStart">content....
   </ion-content>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: are you check it ??

Comment: plz update me..

Answer (score 0):

**Remove `.contenutoStart` from `start.scss` And use following code**

```
ion-content {
    background-image: url('assets/imgs/pergamena.jpg')no-repeat center fixed;
}
```

**In `.html`**

```
<ion-content >
   content....
</ion-content>
```